# Setting some element widths, disabling a button, and initializing some date fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, form

Does anyone have suggestions on how to refactor this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("td,select,th").css("min-width", "150px");

        $("#cancel").button({
            disabled: true
        });
        $(".group-32 input").datepicker();
        $(".group-6 input").datepicker();

        $("#0LevelId").change(function () {
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            $("#0EffectiveDate").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
        });

        $("#1LevelId").change(function () {
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            $("#1EffectiveDate").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
        });

        $("#3LevelId").change(function () {
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            $("#3EffectiveDate").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
        });
    });
```

Comment: ID's can't start with a number.

Comment: This really isn't something I'd worry about. Sure you could probably make it shorter but there's nothing particularly smelly about any of it.

Comment: @Spencer-Ruport thanks for pointing that out. that may be causing an error i have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your code is all the same, you can dynamically create your selector:

```
...

$( '#0LevelId,#1LevelId,#3LevelId' ).change( function(){
    ...
    $( '#' + this.id.substr( 0, 1 ) + 'EffectiveDate' )...
} );
```

Comment: Nice suggestion!

Comment: -1 .. you should use class instead fixed IDs

Comment: @teresko -- that assumes an associated DOM structure that the OP doesn't state he has.  e.g. the ability to write code like `$( this ).find( '.effectiveDate' )`.  Since no structure is given, I gave code based on the OP's code instead of telling him to potentially "refactor everything and do this"

Answer (score 2):

Since you're setting the min-width attribute only once and at the start, consider adding this property to an actual css.

Also, as cwolves noticed, you can select all three elements at once. But instead of specifing them by comma, make all the element to be of the same class.

Besides that, it is a good practice to learn about jQuery's selectors before using it, because otherwise you're kind of missing the whole point of the library.